# django-filter with custom name parameter

Tags: django-filter

I have searched in many places, here, official documentation etc. But I found nothing about my problem:

I want to make a filter for a field with a different name. In this case the field name is "name" and the search property is "value". I did this:

```
class CustomFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    value = django_filters.LookupChoiceFilter(
        field_name="name",
        field_class=forms.CharField,
        lookup_choices=[
            ('icontains', 'contains'), ('istartswith', 'starts with')]
        )

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = {
            'value': STRING_LOOKUPS,
        }
```

I tried also:

- Not using fields property: Error because fields can't be None. So I tried empty list **->** Nothing is filtered
- Not using Meta property **->** Nothing is filtered
- Use the field "name" instead of "value" **->** Filter works but I want to use "value" property and not "name"

Comment: Everything looks correct. Can you update the question to be more specific about what exactly isn't working?

Comment: I don't know what to update is everything there. Try that code, it doesn't works. You can't filter for "value" property filter. Example: `http://apiurl:8000/modelview/?value__icontains=ar` doesn't works.